# SQL merge and consolidate several table with some columns in common

Tags: sql-server, union

I want to join several tables into a single **view**. All tables will have an ID column in common, but not all IDs will be in all tables. Other columns may be in common too. What I need to do is combine these table with all columns and where they are missing, then set to NULL.

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.table1', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.table1;

CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id      INT,
    comp    INT,
    item1   INT
);

INSERT INTO dbo.table1 
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 2),
    (3, 1, 3); -- note: ID 3 not in table 2

-- -------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.table2', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.table2;

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    id      INT,
    comp    INT,
    item2   INT
);

INSERT INTO dbo.table2 
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 2),
    (4, 2, 4); -- note: ID 4 not in table 1


SELECT id, comp, item1, CAST(NULL AS INT) AS item2
FROM dbo.table1
UNION
SELECT id, comp, CAST(NULL AS INT) AS item1, item2
FROM dbo.table2;
```

What I get:

```
id   comp   item1   item2
1    1      NULL    1
1    1      1       NULL
2    2      NULL    2
2    2      2       NULL
3    1      3       NULL
4    2      NULL    4
```

What I expected (hoped for):

```
id   comp   item1   item2
1    1      1       1
2    2      2       2
3    1      3       NULL
4    2      NULL    4
```

So there should obviously be a join on ID somewhere, but how do I consolidate the other columns. There are about 9 different table to join/merge.

Comment: In the expected source why `id = 4` has `comp = 2` and not `1`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group by id, comp` and use max() for each of the `itemx` columns:

```
SELECT t.id, t.comp, max(t.item1) item1, max(t.item2) item2
FROM (
  SELECT id, comp, item1, CAST(NULL AS INT) AS item2
  FROM dbo.table1
  UNION
  SELECT id, comp, CAST(NULL AS INT) AS item1, item2
  FROM dbo.table2
) t
GROUP BY t.id, t.comp
```

You could also use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=48a5378a60e1f9adb1388f07ff051599).
Results:

```
> id | comp | item1 | item2
> -: | ---: | ----: | ----:
>  1 |    1 |     1 |     1
>  2 |    2 |     2 |     2
>  3 |    1 |     3 |  null
>  4 |    2 |  null |     4
```